# Error: Not implemented: window.scrollTo. How do we remove this error from Jest test?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

## The error:

```
console.error node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/virtual-console.js:29
      Error: Not implemented: window.scrollTo
          at module.exports (/Users/me/Projects/my-project/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/not-implemented.js:9:17)
          at /Users/me/Projects/my-project/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/Window.js:594:7
```

Because we are using `window.scrollTo(0,0)`.

Also getting `Not implemented Navigation` for:

`window.location.replace(externa_link)` same error happens with `.assign`.

I tried googling for solutions with react-router, but all examples use some component which contains `window.location`.

Is there a way to avoid this error? Or hide it?

I did some research  and found that the Facebook team isn't going to address it. Is there a way to suppress these errors/warnings when running `jest test`?

Our code doesn't break and all tests pass otherwise.

Comment: Are you running jest with the `--env=jsdom` argument?

Comment: Oh that worked! Thanks :D want to post the answer? We still get this `Error: Not implemented window.scrollTo` but I'll post a new question for that.

Comment: Glad that it worked!

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Try running the jest command with `--env=jsdom`. This will mock most browser functions and will solve your issues.

There are more ways of setting the test environment, take a look at:

https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#testenvironment-string

### Update

This worked for the `window.scrollTo` errors

https://qiita.com/akameco/items/0edfdae02507204b24c8

Comment: Ugh, I may have spoke too soon we actually still get the `Not implemented: navigation` error... I was able to get rid of the `scrollTo` errors. Will have to keep investigating.

Comment: `global.scrollTo = jest.fn()`

Comment: The update link (qiita.com) worked perfectly

Comment: Can anyone explain why this error even happens in the first place?

Answer (score 50):

At the top of the test file after the imports mock it like this :

```
window.scrollTo = jest.fn();
```

Then inside the describe add this:

```
  afterAll(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });
```

so if you are also reseting all mocks after each you will end up with this ::

```
afterEach(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });
  afterAll(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });
```

Answer (score 23):

In `*.test.js` file that calls a component that has `window.scrollTo`

```
it("renders without crashing", () => {
  window.scrollTo = jest.fn()
})
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are just trying to get `window.scrollTo(0,0)` to work properly in your test environment, you can implement it in any of your [`setupFilesAfterEnv`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#setupfilesafterenv-array) files:

```js
window.scrollTo = (x, y) => {
  document.documentElement.scrollTop = y;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The `--env=jsdom` that [@Chris's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57312218) recommended didn't work for me with the latest cra (using `react-scripts@5.0.1`), but the [cra testing documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/running-tests/#initializing-test-environment) mentioned another method that worked for me:

Within `setupTests.ts`:

```
const windowMock = {
  scrollTo: jest.fn(),
};

Object.assign(global, global, windowMock);
```

Basically, we are defining the window functions we want to ignore in a mock object, and then we reassign the global object to contain all the properties of the global object and then all the properties of our window mock object (in this case, the "properties" are functions).

After adding this and rerunning my tests, the `...Not implemented...` error went away. The benefit of this approach is that you can add other window-functions-to-ignore into the `windowMock` object as well and they will stay grouped together to reduce code-clutter.

*Side note*: Based on what the cra documentation says [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/running-tests/#disabling-jsdom) about overriding `--env`, it seems that cra already uses `--env=jsdom` by default.

Answer (score 5):

When using create-react-app it would be best to add the functionality to the setup test file:

```
<project_name>\src\setupTests.js
```

I chose to implement [zgreen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61304613/1621444):

```
window.scrollTo = (x, y) => {
  document.documentElement.scrollTop = y;
}
```

This way, any component that uses that functionality will resolve correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It's working for me.

```
  beforeEach(() => {
    global.window = window
    window.scroll = jest.fn()
    window.HTMLElement.prototype.scrollIntoView = jest.fn()
  })
```